# How to sum up a particular amount of numbers from a list

Tags: python

I would like to sum up a particular amount of numbers from a list.

```
openBids = df_1['openBid'] 
mean = np.mean(openBids) 
std = np.std(openBids) 
rets = np.log(openBids / openBids.shift(1)) 
rets.dropna() 
round(sum(rets.dropna()), 4) # here i only want to add together the first ten numbers from the list for example
```

Can someone tell me how to do it?

Kind regards

Marcel

Comment: What have you tried? Post your code and give details of which pieces you are failing to understand

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show your code and ask specific questions. Do you want to sum all numbers in a list or only a particular range, or even particular indexes?

Comment: openBids = df_1['openBid']
    mean = np.mean(openBids)
    std = np.std(openBids)
    rets = np.log(openBids / openBids.shift(1))
    rets.dropna()
    round(sum(rets.dropna()), 4)  # here i only want to add together the first ten numbers from the list for example

i googled already but couldn find an answer. maybe you guys can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use python's list slicing (assuming `rets.dropna()` returns a list). `rets.dropna()[:10]` will be the first ten from the list.

```
round(sum(rets.dropna()[:10]), 4)
```

See more examples of this syntax in the [python docs tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).